# Is it possible to limit max-date on keyup?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Summary**: I have 5 text inputs, one of which is using the Date attribute. I'm adding validation to the inputs, and one feature I would like to add is to limit the max date. I know I can do this in HTML, however it looks like that only works for the calendar functionality. My thoughts are using keyup, so the user is unable to exceed the year 2050 (for example) within the input in real time.

**Effort:** I looked into the Max attribute in HTML for a while, but it looks like I will have to do this manually in either Js or jQuery. My immediate thought is to pull the value from the input, slice the last 4 integers, and then create text validation from that.

I would rather use a text input and create the entire validation myself, but I would like to keep the calendar functionality without using any external resources. I'm curious if there is a simpler or more efficient way of doing this?

```
<input type="date" class="search__input" id="adv-input-2" placeholder="MM / DD / YY" max="2050-12-31"></span>
```

I've also noticed that using keyup is actually not firing when I use it on a date input, until the entire date is inputted:

```
  // sets limits for date input
  $('#adv-input-2').keyup(function(e) {
      let input = $(this);
  });
```

For example, 10/DD/YYYY will result in `value: ""` until the entire field is completed.

Comment: Why are you not able to use the max attribute?

Comment: The max attribute looks like it only applies to the calendar drop-down functionality. The user is able to exceed the max when they type it. Ex: 12/31/3000 @luekbaja

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this manually then you can use `change` event instead of `keyup` like this way.

```js
// sets limits for date input
$('#adv-input-2').change(function(e) {
  let input = $(this);
   console.log(input.val());
   if(input.prop('max') < input.val()) {
    input.val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="search__input" id="adv-input-2" placeholder="MM / DD / YY" max="2050-12-31"></span>
```

Comment: I'm going to mess around with this after a brief break. This looks like the direction I'm looking to go, but I'm going to see if I can reset the YYYY rather than the entire value. From a user perspective, I think it would be frustrating to have to restart

Comment: It's not possible. When you set the date for the input, it must be a valid date.

The best you can do is set it to a date and then display a message to warn the user they have entered a date later than the max date. You could set it to the current year, or a year that makes no sense if don't want people mistakenly continuing with the current year (e.g. even "0001" will work), but you cannot clear just the year to yyyy.